# Error 405 en Angular aun habilitando CORS

Tags: .net-core

Tengo habilitado CORS y los metodos http en startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                                  builder =>
                                  {
                                      builder.WithHeaders("*");
                                      builder.WithOrigins("*");
                                      builder.WithMethods("*");
                                  });
            });
            services.AddCors(); // Make sure you call this previous to AddMvc
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            // services.AddResponseCaching();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["JWT:Audience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:ClaveSecreta"])
                    )
                };
            });
            services.AddMvc();
            string mySqlConnectionStr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default");
      services.AddDbContext<gestionContext>(options =>
            options.UseMySql(mySqlConnectionStr, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(mySqlConnectionStr)));
            services.AddControllers();

        }
```

Pero obtengo :

**HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 405, statusText: "OK", url: "https://localhost:44355/Cliente", ok: false, …**

Y tengo mi apiclienteservice.ts:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {Response} from '../models/response';
import { cliente } from '../models/cliente';
const httpOption = {
 headers :new HttpHeaders({
   'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
 })
}
@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiclienteService {


 url: string = 'https://localhost:44355/Cliente';

 constructor(
   private http: HttpClient
   ) { 
   
 }
 getClientes():Observable<Response>{

   return this.http.get<Response>(this.url);
   
 }
 add(cliente:cliente): Observable<Response>{
   return this.http.post<Response>(this.url,cliente,httpOption);
 }
 edit(cliente:cliente):Observable<Response>{
   return this.http.put<Response>(this.url,cliente,httpOption);
 }
 delete(id:number):Observable<Response>{
   return this.http.delete<Response>(`${this.url}/${id}`);
 }
}
```

Edito, aca esta el codigo de mi controlador de cliente:

````
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using APIGESTION.Models;
using APIGESTION.Models.Response;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;

namespace APIGESTION.Controllers
{
    
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ClienteController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly gestionContext _context;

        public ClienteController(gestionContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Cliente
     
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetCliente()
        {
            Respuesta orespuesta = new Respuesta();
            orespuesta.Exito = 0;
            try
            {
     
                using (gestionContext db = new gestionContext())
                {
                    var lst = db.Clientes.ToList();
                    orespuesta.Exito = 1;
                    return Ok(lst);
                }
                //return await _context.Clientes.ToListAsync();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                orespuesta.Mensaje = ex.Message;
            }
            return Ok(orespuesta);
        }

        // GET: api/ Cliente/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Cliente>> GetCliente(int id)
        {
            var Cliente = await _context.Clientes.FindAsync(id);

            if (Cliente == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Cliente;
        }

        // PUT: api/Cliente/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutCliente(int id, Cliente cliente)
        {
            if (id != cliente.IdCliente)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(cliente).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ClienteExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/cliente
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Cliente>> PostPais(Cliente cliente)
        {
            _context.Clientes.Add(cliente);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetCliente", new { id = cliente.IdCliente }, cliente);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Cliente/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Cliente>> DeleteCliente(Guid id)
        {
            var cliente = await _context.Clientes.FindAsync(id);
            if (cliente == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Clientes.Remove(cliente);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return cliente;
        }

        private bool ClienteExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Clientes.Any(e => e.IdCliente == id);
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Revisa que la Api soporte los métodos que estás usando. 405 se refiere a que la acción del controlador no soporta el método usado.

Comment: Po eso publique el codigo de la API: builder.WithMethods("*");

Comment: Tambien tengo:     app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod()); en el metodo Configure

Comment: Por eso te dije: `la acción del controlador`, asumiendo que el CORS está bien, ahora revisa las acciones del controlador y asegúrate de que la petición está llegando a la acción correcta con el método correcto.

Comment: Ahi publique el codigo de mi controlador pero no se que puede estar mal.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno despues de tanto indagar y probar me di cuenta que me faltaba pasar el ID del cliente a editar desde Angular:

```
edit(cliente:cliente):Observable<Response>{

   return this.http.put<Response
   (`${this.url}/${cliente.idCliente}`,cliente,httpOption);
 }
```